# HTTPS access only after attempting SSH connection first

Tags: ssl, ssh, https

Whenever I try to connect to `https://github.com` from a Docker container running centos:7 (or ubuntu), the connection cannot be established:

```
$ curl https://github.com -v -m 5
* About to connect() to github.com port 443 (#0)
*   Trying 20.248.137.48...
* Connected to github.com (20.248.137.48) port 443 (#0)
* Initializing NSS with certpath: sql:/etc/pki/nssdb
*   CAfile: /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
  CApath: none
* Operation timed out after 5001 milliseconds with 0 out of 0 bytes received
* Closing connection 0
curl: (28) Operation timed out after 5001 milliseconds with 0 out of 0 bytes received
```

However, after I run `ssh github.com` I can access the site using HTTPS as well:

```
$ ssh github.com
Permission denied (publickey).
```

```
$ curl https://github.com -v -m 5
* About to connect() to github.com port 443 (#0)
*   Trying 20.248.137.48...
* Connected to github.com (20.248.137.48) port 443 (#0)
* Initializing NSS with certpath: sql:/etc/pki/nssdb
*   CAfile: /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
  CApath: none
* SSL connection using TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
* Server certificate:
*       subject: CN=github.com,O="GitHub, Inc.",L=San Francisco,ST=California,C=US
*       start date: Feb 14 00:00:00 2023 GMT
*       expire date: Mar 14 23:59:59 2024 GMT
*       common name: github.com
*       issuer: CN=DigiCert TLS Hybrid ECC SHA384 2020 CA1,O=DigiCert Inc,C=US
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.29.0
> Host: github.com
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
```

This only works if I actually try to connect using SSH. I have tried adding the SSH key fingerprint using `ssh-keyscan` but it seems that this has no effect. The presence of the known_hosts file has no impact on whether or not I can connect using HTTPS.

How can I get this to work, without having to use SSH to authenticate the host first?

Comment: What happens if you use other programs for accessing the same URL? Based on your description it could be a bit too restrictive configured firewall on GitHub side. Some firewall (provider) use TLS fingerprinting to identify the client before even the TLS connection has been established (no response to SERVER HELLO message). Not sure how good the identification works and why some clients may be blocked. By using ssh the firewall places your IP in some allowed list which also makes https works. But that is just a guess, you can use Wireshark to check if this matches on network level.

Comment: I'm not sure if this gets blocked on their firewall level. I've tried `curl`, `wget` and the git client so far to no avail. The reason I think this might be something local is because I can spin up an identical container on the same machine and have one able to access github.com while the other can't (until I connect using SSH).